# Combinations/ permutations of numbers in array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I need to get all the permutations in array of a concrete length, e.g.

```
source = { 1,2,3,4 }, count=1 => {{1},{2},{3},{4}}
source = { 1,2,3,4 }, count=2 => {{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4}}
source = { 1,2,3,4 }, count=3 => {{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,3,4},{2,3,4}}
source = { 1,2,3,4 }, count=4 => {{1,2,3,4}}
```

where source is a source array, and count is the permutation length.
I need to write a method with the following specification:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> GenerateAllPermutations<T>(T[] source, int count)
{}
```

I use the following method to get all the permutations:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> 
    GetKCombs<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length) where T : IComparable
{
    if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });
    return GetKCombs(list, length - 1)
        .SelectMany(t => list.Where(o => o.CompareTo(t.Last()) > 0), 
            (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
}
```

And the output of this is (for a list of `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and a length of `2`)

```
{1,2} {1,3} {1,4} {2,3} {2,4} {3,4}
```

So the question is: How can I invoke the `GetKCombs` method in the `GenerateAllPermutations` method with correct conversion of types?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You need to get around that IComparable constraint? You can make wrapper struct with index (from original array) and redirect CompareTo to that index.

Comment: Perhaps you meant combinations, not permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the `IComparable` constraint to the generic parameter of your permutations method as well, then call it like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> GenerateAllPermutations<T>(
        T[] source,
        int count)
        where T : IComparable
{
     return GetKCombs(source, count).Select(x => x.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: This seems to be ok! Thank you!